# Move data from 5 column on 5 line (in loop)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a newbie in VBA Excel and in need your help !
I have a table with 5 column with many data (4000 lines about)
For each colum and for each line, i want a new line.

The cell is the result of previous calculation.

For example with this table

Before :

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell A1 | Cell B1 | Cell C1 | Cell D1 |
| Cell A2 | Cell B2 | Cell C2 | Cell D2 |

After :

| Column A |
| --- |
| Cell A1 |
| Cell B1 |
| Cell C1 |
| Cell D1 |
| Cell A2 |
| Cell B2 |
| Cell C2 |
| Cell D2 |

Thank you very much for your help.

I'm looking for help to implement an excel macro (or any other solution in Excel) to meet my needs

Comment: About your question, just do a loop and transpose each row. There are millions of examples. Anyways, please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Look into `=Tocol()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then could utilize `TOCOL()`.

```
=TOCOL(A:D,1)
```

For ***Excel-2021,2019*** could use `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTERXML()`.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,$A$1:$D$16),"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW($A1)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your this complete and faster reply